# Order by difference of two columns from two subquerys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have two tables

```
Table1 with columns
    f_id, a_id

Table2 with columns
    a_id, a_name
```

And I am trying to find a query where I can order the `f_id`s by the difference of the count of `a_id`s in two subquerys. Subquery 1 would basically be something like:

```
SELECT f_id,
       count(a_id) 
FROM Table1 
GROUP BY f_id
```

While Subquery 2 would then look a little like this:

```
SELECT Table1.f_id, 
       count(Table1.a_id) 
FROM Table1, Table2 
WHERE
     Table1.a_id = Table2.a_id 

WHERE Table2.a_name= "User Input1" OR "User Input2" 
GROUP BY f_id
```

Now the main Query is supposed to order the `f_id`s of `Table1` by the difference of the count of the subquerys, I hope you get the idea even though I might have not explained it very well

Sample Data and desired output:

```
Table1 with columns
    f_id, a_id
    5,    3
    5,    4
    6,    2
    6,    3

Table2 with columns
    a_id, a_name
    2,    "foo"
    3,    "bar"
    4,    "too"
```

Now considering that user input is bar and too I would like to have the following output

```
Output with order by difference of the two counts:
   r_id     difference of counts
   5,       0
   6,       1
```

Comment: post with sample data and your desired output.Also check your second query..it has syntax errors

Comment: Added example data, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand correctly this is what you looking for:

```
SELECT t1.f_id, (t1.cnt1 - t2.cnt2) AS DifferenceOfCount
FROM (SELECT f_id, COUNT(a_id) AS cnt1
      FROM Table1 
      GROUP BY f_id) t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT Table1.f_id AS f_id, COUNT(Table1.a_id) AS cnt2
            FROM Table1 
            INNER JOIN Table2 
            ON Table1.a_id=Table2.a_id 
            WHERE Table2.a_name= "foo" OR table2.a_name = "bar" 
            GROUP BY f_id) t2
ON t1.f_id = t2.f_id
ORDER BY DifferenceOfCount
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e842b/3) so you can see how it's work.

You should notice that i use INNER JOIN syntax to join two table instead of your old fashion way for doing that (it's better practice to do that...)

Also if this query will take user input i think you should create stored procedure for that... How that's look like you can see [HERE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/76293/2)!

Note: this is MySQL but something similar (maybe the same should be in Sql Server), I'm not quite sure what you use because you tag both of them...

GL!

Comment: Thank you so much for this, works just as it's supposed to be!

Comment: Your welcome! I'm glad that I could help... you're done almost whole job with your subquery I just fit them to work what you need :) P.S. if it's work as it supposed to than you can mark this answer as accepted :)